# Does GNU Make support '%' in a filename?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In GNU Make is it possible to have a dependency on a file that includes a `%` in the filename? I have something like this:

```
foo: results(10%).dat
    gnuplot config.plt
```

While I can of course choose a different filename it would be nice to know if `%` should always be avoided or if there is a simple way to escape it (I've tried `\`, `\\`, and `%%` with no luck).

**Edit:** My problems seems to be more subtle. It seems to not work because of a combination of matching and a percent filename:

```
all: foo.txt bar.txt

PERCENT := %

foo%txt bar%txt: results(10$(PERCENT)).dat
    touch foo$*txt bar$*txt
```

This fails but if the filename doesn't have a `%` it's fine.

Comment: I just stumbled into a similar problem... I have a directory that has a '%' character in it, and Make is supposed to process a list of files in those directories. It stops at the first one. Take out the % and it works fine. Did you ever figured out a root cause?

Comment: I have actually been escaping this similarly with a variable like that and ran into the problem _again_ and scratched my head for a while until figuring out the problem was actually with having parenthesis in a target same. Yours is in a dependency name so it might not be the same trouble, but don't try to use `$<` or similar vars if their contents have parenthesis in them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
PERCENT := %
foo: results(10$(PERCENT)).dat
    gnuplot config.plt
```

(where the spaces before `gnuplot` are a tab character really).

Answer (score 1):

Percent characters are fine in normal rules like the first rule you posted, it should work as-is.

As for the second example, there doesn't seem to be any reason why you would want a pattern rule:

```
targets := foo.txt bar.txt

.PHONY: all
all: $(targets)

$(targets): results(10%).dat
    touch $(targets)
```

`%` can be escaped in *static* pattern rules

```
$(targets): %.txt: \%%.txt #dependencies will be %foo.txt and %bar.txt respectively
```

But there doesn't seem to be any way to escape `%` in an implicit pattern rule like your second example.