# Make and Percent Sign in Paths

Tags: jenkins, makefile, gnu-make

I seem to have hit a quirk regarding Makefiles, list processing, and pattern rules. When my source is installed in a directory whose name includes '%', it fails to build correctly. I've boiled it down to a simple test case anybody could run.

I have the following Makefile:

```
INSTALL_DIR=$(shell pwd)/idir

INSTALL_TREE  =
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir1
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir2
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir3

create_tree: $(INSTALL_TREE)
$(INSTALL_TREE):
    mkdir -p $@
```

I put this in a directory called test1, and when I run it I get exactly what I want... all the directories listed in INSTALL_TREE are created:

```
% make -n
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test1/idir/dir1
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test1/idir/dir2
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test1/idir/dir3
```

Now use the exact same Makefile in a directory called test%2, and this is what I get:

```
% make -n
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test2%/idir/dir1
```

It stops after the first directory. Interestingly, if the first directory does not have a % sign, they all get generated..., e.g.,

```
INSTALL_TREE  =
INSTALL_TREE += ./idir/dir4
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir1
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir2
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir3
```

gives me:

```
mkdir -p dir4
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test2%/idir/dir1
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test2%/idir/dir2
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test2%/idir/dir3
```

The other interesting thing is that the files names are correct... if the % were being misinterpreted as a prefix rule or something you might expect some substitution, but if I let it create the directories it does the absolute right thing.

I tried escaping the % character, but to no avail. Adding this code:

```
PERCENT := %
ITREE = $(subst $(PERCENT),$(PERCENT)$(PERCENT),$(INSTALL_TREE))
create_tree2: $(ITREE)

$(ITREE):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Just yielded

```
mkdir -p /home/christopher.arguin/test/test2%%/idir/dir1
```

The substitution worked, but it didn't actually escape the percent sign. Neither did replacing "%" with "$(PERCENT)", as the filename just contained $(PERCENT) in it afterward.

I found two related questions, 
[Does GNU Make support '%' in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419859/does-gnu-make-support-in-a-filename)
and [How to correctly escape "%" sign when using pattern rules and patsubst in GNU make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232784/how-to-correctly-escape-sign-when-using-pattern-rules-and-patsubst-in-gnu-ma)
but neither of those suffered the basic problem I have... that the directory my source is in is out of my control.

Background:
   *The reason is this an issue for me is that I am trying to migrate to Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline. When Jenkins detects a commit, it creates a workspace based on the name of the branch. If your branch naming convention happens to have slashes in it, Jenkins does the right thing and converts those to "%2F". My makefiles are running afoul of those.*

Comment: Can you make a symbolic link?

Comment: Sadly not, since in this case the names of the workspace are handled by Jenkins.

Comment: It looks like the Jenkins guys are actively working on it now to avoid this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34564

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Can you make a symbolic link *to the workspace created by Jenkins?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A target containing `%` defines a pattern rule, and pattern rules with multiple targets are processed differently:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. **The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets.**

You can fix this by quoting `%` when defining the path rule. Note that this isn't necessary for the dependencies of `create_tree` as that is a regular rule, in fact it won't work if you do, as make will look for targets with a literal `\%`.

```
INSTALL_DIR := $(abspath .)/idir

INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir1
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir2
INSTALL_TREE += $(INSTALL_DIR)/dir3

.PHONY: create_tree
create_tree: $(INSTALL_TREE)
$(subst %,\%,$(INSTALL_TREE)):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: I see; I had tried doing the same thing into a variable, but that gets interpreted too early. It has to be done as part of the pattern directly.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it does solve the problem (and seems to be the only solution to the problem), but in my case this would involve rewriting a lot of rules since you can't just prepare an escaped version of the string. As it happens Jenkins was already doing a work-around to avoid this issue entirely, and just updating to this week's version pulled in the fix.

Comment: @ChrisArguin It'll work as a variable as long as you only use it for the target, when used in place of the dependencies you need the paths unquoted.

Comment: Apparently I was also trying to escape % incorrectly (for some reason I thought it was '%%' not '\%' ), so that explains why I thought it didn't work. Using your 'subst' function into a variable works fine.Thanks!